# Azure AD B2C Sign Up with Phone

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In Azure AD B2C the Sign up process with Phone is expecting the emailId during the sign up process.
Our use case is that we just need to ask the user only Phone number during the sign up process. Is there a way that we can avoid asking the emailid from the user during Sign up process with Phone?

Thanks,
SathKaal

Comment: This custom policy sample might help: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

Just move the comment to answer so that this post can be treated as resolved.

OTP (one-time password) should be the option for you. The sample which juunas mentioned is helpful.

And you can follow this official document [Set up phone sign-up and sign-in with custom policies in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication), which allows you to use phone number to sign up and sign in in Azure Active Directory B2C.